# Smypy prinint format of equations with upper and lower indices

Tags: python, printing, scipy, sympy

I have a code that is someting like this

```
print("Gamma^",syms[i],"_",syms[j],syms[k], "=", syms[1], syms[2]**2)
```

When I print in jupyter-lab it looks like this

```
Gamma^ r _ phi phi = r theta**2
Gamma^ theta _ r theta = r theta**2
Gamma^ theta _ theta r = r theta**2
Gamma^ theta _ phi phi = r theta**2
Gamma^ phi _ r phi = r theta**2
Gamma^ phi _ theta phi = r theta**2
Gamma^ phi _ phi r = r theta**2
Gamma^ phi _ phi theta = r theta**2
```

Is there a way to make it something like this

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pEOHx.png)

or very similar at least

Answer (score 0):

I am able to obtain something similar with

```
Gamma = IndexedBase('Gamma')
phi,theta,r = symbols('phi,theta,r')
display(Eq(Gamma[phi,theta]**phi,r*theta**2))
```

[image]